# break the text in new line if it doesnt fit in span

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a panel which is divided into two parts: left and right panel.
In right panel i have unsorted list of element which indeed has list of elements. 
Each of li has tag which has 2 spans one for icon file and text content which are side by side.

Currently: when the text length increases the whole span is moved to new line. spans are not side by side anymore.

I need to achieve, span1 & span2 should be side by side, and when text increases in span2, span 2 should grow vertically than moving completely to new line.

[jsfiddle for test application](https://jsfiddle.net/user_28/dgb5uv3x/3/)

```css
.left_side_panel{
float: left;
width:50%;
padding-right:1.25rem;
}
.right_side_panel{
float: right;
width:20%;
padding-left:1.25rem;
}
.Panel_Info_Contents{
margin-bottom:3.75rem;
}
.userguide{
list-style: none;
}
.userguide li{
border: 5px solid yellow;
display: block;
min-height: 1.75rem;
margin-bottom:0.625rem;
}
a{
cursor: pointer;
color:#ffff;
text-decoration:none;
}
.guide_icon--file{
border: 2px solid green;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-right:0.625rem;
width:1.75rem;
height: 1.75rem;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.guide_entrydetails{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
color:red;
border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="client">
    <div class="middlePanel__client__overview">
      <div class="left_side_panel">
      </div>
      <div class="right_side_panel">
        <div class="Panel_Info_Contents">
            <ul class="userguide">
                <li>
                    <a title="user guide hand book and some more details to reproduce the issue" href="">
                        <span class="guide_icon--file">
                        </span>
                        <span class="guide_entrydetails">
                            user guide hand book and some more details to reproduce the issue and some more things and some more
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user_28/dgb5uv3x/3/)

[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TUaL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.left_side_panel {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}

.right_side_panel {
  float:right;
  width: 50%; /* for demo purposes */
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
}

.Panel_Info_Contents {
  margin-bottom: 3.75rem;
}

.userguide {
  list-style: none;
}

.userguide li {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  display: block;
  min-height: 1.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

a {
  display: flex; /* this */
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.guide_icon--file {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  width: 1.75rem;
  height: 1.75rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.guide_entrydetails {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="client">
  <div class="middlePanel__client__overview">
    <div class="left_side_panel">
    </div>
    <div class="right_side_panel">
      <div class="Panel_Info_Contents">
        <ul class="userguide">
          <li>
            <a title="user guide hand book and some more details to reproduce the issue" href="">
              <span class="guide_icon--file">I
                        </span>
              <span class="guide_entrydetails">
                            user guide hand book and some more details to reproduce the issue and some more things and some more
                        </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wil give a try now